# TWebBrowser and the Tab key

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer

When using Delphi 2007 and the TWebBrowser control is embedded in an ActiveX control (ActiveForm), the tab key does not work. What is the fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

use [EmbeddedWB](http://www.bsalsa.com/) and enable **TabStop**

Comment: indeed.  i've emailed the author.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify: The tab key does not work within a form on a web page. Setting TabStop to true does not fix this problem.